# Downloading surface water monthly multi- images from 2010-2015 in defined region? GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to download data of surface water monthly history of region[73,25,105,40]from 2010 to 2015. referencing the others codes I write the codes as follows. But When I Run, there is no action of the GEE.

```
var AOI=ee.Geometry.Rectangle([73,25,105,40]);
var datasuface=ee.ImageCollection('JRC/GSW1_0/MonthlyHistory').filterDate('2010-10-1', '2015-10-18').filterBounds(AOI);
var list=datasuface.toList(length);
    for (var i=1;i<length;i++){
         var image=ee.Image(list.get(i));
         var name1=ee.String('Monthwater')
                    .cat(ee.String(ee.Number(i)))
                    .getInfo();
         print(name1)
         Export.image.toDrive({ 
               image: image,
               description:name1,
               scale: 250,
               maxPixels:1e13
         });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are combining server-side and client-side objects.

In your case where you start the loop, i is client side, while length is server side.
Use getInfo() on length or just fill in 61 (which is the size of your collection). The latter is way faster.

Also, removing the getInfo in the variable to get the name of the task speeds up your program. Probably, you also want to set region to your AOI in your export images, as it otherwise defaults to your current view.

```
// set the collection
var AOI = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([73,25,105,40]);
var datasuface = ee.ImageCollection('JRC/GSW1_0/MonthlyHistory')
                    .filterDate('2010-10-1', '2015-10-18').filterBounds(AOI);

// get the size of the collection and cast colelciton to a list
var length = datasuface.size();
var list = datasuface.toList(length);

// run a for loop to export images
for (var i = 1; i < 61; i++){
     var image = ee.Image(list.get(i));
     var name1 = 'Monthwater' + i;
     print(name1)
     Export.image.toDrive({ 
           image: image,
           description: name1,
           scale: 250,
           maxPixels: 1e13,
           region: AOI
     });
}
```

[Link to script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/b1a80cf96f3adf823270bc8e2149acdd)